# How can I read multiple xsd strings into xmlschema

Tags: python, xml, xsd, python-xmlschema

I have multiple XSD strings in my Python program, for example.

```
xsd1 = '''<?xml version...
   <xs:schema targetNamespace="...
'''
xsd2 = '''...'''

import xmlschema
schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema([xsd1, xsd2]) # it seems xmlschema does not accept such arguments
# then using schema to validate xml files
```

The two XSD have different target name spaces. How can I read them into *xmlschema* and validate xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the xmlschema.XMLSchema() constructor would accept a list of file locations and assemble a single XSD model from them all (Eclipse EMF XSD model can do this). But it looks as if xmlschema does not do that trick.

The workaround is to create a single wrapper XSD that imports/includes the other XSDs, and then give the wrapper XSD to xmlschema.

Comment: thank you @kimbert. Is there a way to import/include other xsd strings considering i am using python string instead of files.

Comment: https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#create-a-schema-instance . Finding and reading documentation is a skill worth acquiring :-)